# How to trigger an useEffect if the array is greater than

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to trigger an useEffect, only when my images array is greater than 0. But in the console, I notice that its being triggered twice, when its 0, and greater than 0.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { myModules } from '#/redux/modules';

    const Component = () => {
     const images = useSelector(getImages)
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      useEffect( () =>  {
        dispatch(myModules.actions.setMaskVisible(true));
      }, [images.length > 0, dispatch]);
    
    }
```

How can I make this useEffect work ONLY when images array is greater than 0 ?

Comment: Use a simple if, inside the effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { myModules } from '#/redux/modules';

    const Component = () => {
     const images = useSelector(getImages)
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      useEffect( () =>  {
          if (images.length > 0) {
            dispatch(myModules.actions.setMaskVisible(true));
          }
      }, [images, dispatch]);
    
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Both of these approach should work

```html
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { myModules } from '#/redux/modules';

    const Component = () => {
     const images = useSelector(getImages)
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      useEffect( () =>  {
        if (images.length > 0) {
          dispatch(myModules.actions.setMaskVisible(true));
        }
      }, [images, dispatch]);
    
    }
```

```html
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { myModules } from '#/redux/modules';

    const Component = () => {
     const images = useSelector(getImages);
     const [triggerEffect, setTriggerEffect] = useState(false);
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
     if (images.length > 0) setTriggerEffect(!triggerEffect);
      useEffect( () =>  {
        dispatch(myModules.actions.setMaskVisible(true));
      }, [triggerEffect, dispatch]);
    
    }
```